# Java JDBC First () in ResultSet is not working?

Tags: java

I want to change the position of the cursor to the first row but I don't know why my code is not working.when I add `rs2.first()`:

and also I am getting this error :

This method should only be called on ResultSet objects that are scrollable (type TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE).

```
        try{                    
      String driver = "org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver";
      Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
      String url = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/test";
      Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
      String query = "select * from APP.RANKING";
      Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
      Statement stmt2 = conn.createStatement();
      ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
      ResultSet rs2 = stmt2.executeQuery(query);
      while (rs.next()){             
          String BID = rs.getString("BALLOT_ID");
          String CN = rs.getString("CANDIDATE_NAME");
          String ROID = rs.getString("USER_ID");
          Ro1_ID = ROID;
          String RA = rs.getString("RANK");
          int rowNum = rs.getRow();
          int rowNum2;
          boolean In_check = false;
          while(rs2.next()){               
                  In_ballot.addElement(BID);  
                  
                }

          rs2.First();
          In_ballot.addElement(BID);  
              }
         
         }
    catch(Throwable e) {
                System.err.println(e.getMessage());        
                }
    this.InB_list.setModel(In_ballot);
```

Comment: rs2.beforeFirst() moves the cursor before the first row, not to the first row. I dont see rs2.first(); in your code

Comment: sorry I modified my code.al also i added the error I am getting

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, calling [`createStament()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#createStatement%28%29) in a connection results in every `ResultSet` having type 'TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY' - This results in the exception you see using [`first()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#first%28%29).

Instead, use another versions of `createStatement`, like [this one](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#createStatement%28int,%20int%29).

[This sample](http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.4.2.1/devguide/cdevconcepts22641.html) of creating scrollable `ResultSet`s in Derby might help.