# How to check resultset is empty or null in java

Tags: java, resultset

I have a `sql` query to run in my java class (Servlet) what i am trying to do if there is no data in database for that query then want to do something else.

In simple terms i am checking if there is no data in resultset than want to do something else,but that's not working

**What i have tried**

```
String str = null;
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    LinkedHashMap<Object, Object> lhm = null;
    LinkedList<LinkedHashMap<Object, Object>> mainList = new LinkedList<LinkedHashMap<Object, Object>>();

    String sql;

    try {
        Connection con = DBConnection.createConnection();
        Statement statement = con.createStatement();

        sql = "select distinct a.DISPLAYCOUNTERNAME from DISPLAYCOUNTERNAMES a,DISPLAYCOUNTER b where a.DISPLAYCOUNTERCODE=b.DISPLAYCOUNTERCODE and USERNAME='"
                + userName + "'";

        System.out.println(sql);
        ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql);

        if (!resultSet.isBeforeFirst()) { // if there is no data
            lhm = new LinkedHashMap<Object, Object>();
            lhm.put("outlet", "NoData");
            mainList.add(lhm);
            str = gson.toJson(mainList);
        }

            while (resultSet.next()) { // if there is data
                lhm = new LinkedHashMap<Object, Object>();
                counterName = resultSet.getString("DISPLAYCOUNTERNAME");
                 System.out.println("counternam"+counterName);
                lhm.put("Counter name", counterName);

                mainList.add(lhm);
                str = gson.toJson(mainList);

            }


        System.out.println(str);
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.getWriter().write(str);

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("SQL Issues 2...");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The above code is throwing error as `SQL Issues 2...
java.sql.SQLException: This method should only be called on ResultSet objects that are scrollable (type TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE).`

I don't know what i am doing wrong here,any-kind of help will be appreciated

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9857257/java-jdbc-first-in-resultset-is-not-working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try modifying the line:

`Statement statement = con.createStatement();`

to

```
Statement statement = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, 
                                          ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `next` but switch to use a do/while loop, if the first call to `next` returns true then the row pointer points to the first row in the result set so you must read it before calling `next` again

```
if (!resultSet.next()) { 
   // do no data stuff
} else { 
    do { 
      //handle result set data
    } while (rs.next()); 
}
```